# how to use first child in my code?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/eFhRE/1/ I wan't to make the a tag with id shoshone red with help of :first-child. Must be only the a tag with id shoshone and only with the use of :first-child. The rest of the a tags must remain blue.

Here is the html code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="mosonkhani">
    <a id="shoshone" href="#">Potsmare</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dolores</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quiddam</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the css code I have tried with:

```
a { color:#00f; }
.mosonkhani:first-child {
  color:#f00;
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Try `.mosonkhani > a:first-child `

Comment: Curious, is there a good reason why you can't just use an ID selector? Too specific?

Comment: Agreed. If the link has an ID there is no reason to get more specific that that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.mosonkhani > :first-child {
  color:#f00;
}
```

You want the first child **within** `.mosonkhani`.  What you had was an element with class 
`mosonkhani` which is also the first child.

http://jsfiddle.net/eFhRE/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
.mosonkhani > a:first-child {...}
```

.mosnokhani:first-child would give every element (with class="mosonkhani")thats the first child inside an element the red color property.

Well .mosonkhani > a {...} would work in this case too.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need first-child.

```
a { color:#00f; }

.mosonkhani > a {
  color:#f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eFhRE/6/

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo class *:first-child* matches the first element in its prefix.

Your code will match the first ".mosonkhani" element in the document.

If you have to select the first '*a*' (link) element in any .mosokhani, use:

```
.mosonkhani a:first-child
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Your description of `first-child` is incorrect.  It matches an element which is the first child within its parent element.  The initial code does not match the first `.mosonkhani` in the document.  It matches any `mosonkhani` element which is the first child in its parent element.

Comment: Also, your solution matches every `a` as they are all first children:  http://jsfiddle.net/eFhRE/8/

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to complicate this width `first-child` or `nth-child`

Your anchor tag has an ID...use it

**CSS**

```
#shoshone {
    color:red;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/eFhRE/7/)

Answer (score -1):

You are using `:first-child` wrong.

```
.mosonkhani > a:first-child {
  color:#f00;
}
```

That should do what you want.

Your Fiddle, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffijoe/eFhRE/2/

`first-child` will get you the first instance of whatever your selector targets. I *personally* feel `first-child` is a mis-leading name.

Comment: It's not misleading at all. It does really mean "the first child of its parent". It does not mean "the first instance of whatever your selector targets" as you state - that's actually jQuery's `:first`. If you replaced `a:first-child` with `ul:first-child`, it wouldn't match, because the `ul` is the second child, despite being the first `ul`.

Comment: @BoltClock They do the same according to this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffijoe/saLdB/ . When I read `ul:first-child`, I understand it as "the first child within the ul element", even though I know that's not what it actually does.

Comment: That's because that `li` is *both* the first `ul li` and the first child of the `ul`. I think the misunderstanding lies not in the `:first-child` pseudo-class specifically, but pseudo-classes in general. The basic idea is that a pseudo-class acts just like a regular class selector, except that its name describes what it actually does, which means it describes the element you are selecting and not some other element that is related to it.

Comment: No, I understand perfectly fine :) `a:hover` makes sense to *me*, but I *personally* still think 'a:first-child' sounds as if wanting to select the first child of the targeted `a` tag. This is still just something personal, and I have stated it as such. I know how they work, else I would not be able to give a working example. If you look at the OP, the asker appears to think the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
.mosonkhani>a {
    color:#f00;
}
```

Yes. I know i am not using the first-child.